# In how many ways can five balls be chosen so that....

Tags: probability, factorial

In how many ways can five balls be chosen so that

(a) two are red and three are black?
(b) three are red and two are black?

out of $7$ black and $8$ red

Should I use permutation?
or $8\times7\times7\times6\times5$?

And why?

Comment: the question is incomplete , five balls be chosen out of what ?

Comment: How many balls are there of each color?

Comment: @Jeremy 8 red 7 black

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw  8 red 7 black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use permutation here because the ordering is not important .

You will have to choose combination here .

choosing $2$ red out of $8$ red = $_8C_2$ ways 
choosing $3$ black out of $7$ black = $_7C_3$ ways

therefore total number of ways of doing (a)= $_8C_2 * _7C_3$

Comment: THANKS! i got 980 is that correct?

Comment: so permutation is when order matters and combination when order does not matter?

Comment: it should be correct